# How can I take image at webcam with javaFX at win7 64bit?

Tags: java, webcam, javafx

I want to take an image from webcam. How can I do this?
If is there any sample codes for your advice library, it's better than other for me.

I examined these:

- Jmyron
- Java Media Framework
- JavaCV
- lt-civil

These are not useful. These do not work or do not have sample code.
Have you got any advice?

Comment: here is a link with an answer which shows code used to capture an image using It-civil: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10041895

Answer (score 3):

Try this project:

http://github.com/rladstaetter/isight-java/

and the corresponding blog post

http://ladstatt.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/using-isight-camera-with-javafx.html

Keep in mind that you'll have to have the correct opencv dll for your architecture (x64)

Answer (score 1):

I stripped down OpenIMAJ Core Video Capture Library to get images from webcam. It works well on my macbook, linux deskdop and windows 7 env.

You don't need to install anything, two jars are all you need. You can find the example from my site:

http://www.sleepingdumpling.com/blog/download/jvideoinput/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a [Demonstration JavaFX Camera capture application using LTI-CIVIL](http://code.google.com/p/jfxcamera/)

You are correct that the LTI-CIVIL library is 32 bit only, so perhaps not useful In your case if 64 bit is an imperative.

Comment: The link has nothing? or am I not seeing it

Comment: Link works for me - links to a google project containing source code for a project to display and control an LTI-CIVIL camera capture from a JavaFX scene.